# form included with ui:include not filling bean

Tags: jsf, dynamic, primefaces, uiinclude

This is problem:
we have main page with included xhtml containing form. commandButton invoke action, but scoped bean doesn't fills by value of inputText. Code below:

welcome_file.xhtml

```
  <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>XHTML Page</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="CSS/style.css" />    
  </h:head>
    <h:body>  
        <f:facet name="last">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/CSS/style.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="CSS/style.css" />
        </f:facet>
    <f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview">
        <p:layout  fullPage="true" resizeTitle="resize">  
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="68" id="north" style="font-size: 100%; text-align: center;" header="КРАУДСОРСИНГОВАЯ ПЛАТФОРМА MEPHORCE">
            <h:outputText value="#{clientBean.clientFIO.get(0)} #{clientBean.clientFIO.get(1)} #{clientBean.clientFIO.get(2)}" style="font-size: 100%; text-align: left;"/>    
            </p:layoutUnit>   
                       <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" header="Меню" style="height:580px;overflow:hidden;" size="225">
            <h:panelGroup id="menu" layout="block">

        <h:form>
        <f:ajax render=":content">
            <ul>
                <li><h:commandLink value="Профиль" action="#{beanClient.setPage('profile')}" /></li>            
                <li><h:commandLink value="Мои проекты" action="#{beanClient.setPage('my_projects')}" /></li>            
                <li><h:commandLink value="Новый проект" action="#{beanClient.setPage('new_project')}"  /></li>
                <li><h:commandLink value="Чат с модератором" action="#{beanClient.setPage('mod_chat')}" /></li> 
                <li><h:commandLink value="Сообщество" action="#{beanClient.setPage('community')}" /></li> 
                <li><h:commandLink value="Выход" action="#{clientBean.logout()}" /></li>
            </ul>
        </f:ajax>
    </h:form>
         </h:panelGroup>
            </p:layoutUnit>
 <p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center">
  <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/client/#{beanClient.page}.xhtml" />
  </h:panelGroup>
  </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="0" style="width:0px; display:none;" id="east">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" resizable="true" id="south">

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>

 </f:view>
</h:body>
```

new_project.xhtml

```
    <table width="100%" height="100%" >
  <h:form id="form">  
      <p:growl id="growl" class="ui-growl"  showDetail="false"  sticky="false" life="10000"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2"   styleClass="h_pgrid-style"  >  

    <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Название: "  styleClass="el-style"/>  
    <p:inputText id="title"  size="45" required="true"  value="#{projectBean.prTitle}" >                       
    </p:inputText>

    </h:panelGrid></td>

        <td>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2"   styleClass="h_pgrid-style"  >  


    <f:facet name="footer">    
        <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
            <p:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" value="Создать" process="@this" action="#{projectBean.CreateNewProjectSubmit(clientBean.clientId)}" 
                             update="growl"  ajax="true"/> 
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>          

    </h:panelGrid>  

    </td>           

    </tr>
   </h:form>    
  </table>
```

project bean class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText;
import trg.dao.ProjectsDAOImpl;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class ProjectBean
{
    private List<Project> projectList;

    private int prId;
    private String prTitle;
    private String prDesctiption;
    private java.util.Date prDate;
    private int prBudget;
    private String prStatus;
    private int prMod;

    public int getPrId()
    {
        return prId;
    }

    public void setPrId(int prId)
    {
        this.prId=prId;
    }

    public String getPrTitle() {
        System.out.println ("GetPrTitle:"+prTitle);
        return prTitle;
    }

    public void setPrTitle(String prTitle) {
        this.prTitle = prTitle;
        System.out.println ("SetPrTitle:"+prTitle);
    }

    public String getPrDesctiption() {
        return prDesctiption;
    }

    public void setPrDesctiption(String prDesctiption) {
        this.prDesctiption = prDesctiption;
    }

    public java.util.Date getPrDate() {
        return prDate;
    }

    public void setPrDate(java.util.Date prDate) {
        this.prDate = prDate;
    }

    public int getPrBudget() {
        return prBudget;
    }

    public void setPrBudget(int prBudget) {
        this.prBudget = prBudget;
    }

    public String getPrStatus() {
        return prStatus;
    }

    public void setPrStatus(String prStatus) {
        this.prStatus = prStatus;
    }

    public int getPrMod() {
        return prMod;
    }

    public void setPrMod(int prMod) {
        this.prMod = prMod;
    }


    public List<Project> getProjectList(int cl_id) throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  {
      ProjectsDAOImpl projectsDAOImpl = new ProjectsDAOImpl();

      projectList = projectsDAOImpl.getProjectListClient(cl_id);
      return projectList;  

  } 

      public void CreateNewProjectSubmit(int cl_id) throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  {

      FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

      /*ProjectsDAOImpl projectsDAOImpl = new ProjectsDAOImpl();
      projectsDAOImpl.createNewProject(prTitle, prDesctiption, prDate, prBudget, prStatus, prMod, cl_id);
*/
      FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Проект успешно создан","");
      context.addMessage(null, message);    

  }
```

clientBean.java

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import trg.dao.ClientDAOImpl;
import trg.service.SessionBean;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ClientBean {
    private int clientId;
    private String clFam;
    private String clFirst;
    private String clSec;
    private String clPass;  

    public int getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getClFam() {
        return clFam;
    }

    public void setClFam(String clFam) {
        this.clFam = clFam;
    }


  public String getClFirst() {
        return clFirst;
    }

     public void setClFirst(String clFirst) {
        this.clFirst = clFirst;
    }     

  public String getClSec() {
        return clSec;
    }

     public void setClSec(String clSec) {
        this.clSec = clSec;
    }     

 public String getClPass() {
        return clPass;
    }

     public void setClPass(String clPass) {
        this.clPass = clPass;
    }             


public List<Client> getClientsList() throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  {
      ClientDAOImpl clientDAOImpl = new ClientDAOImpl();

      List<Client> clientlist = clientDAOImpl.getClientList();

      return clientlist;  

  }

public List<String> getClientFIO() throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  {
       ClientDAOImpl clientDAOImpl = new ClientDAOImpl();

      List<Client> clientFIO = clientDAOImpl.getFio(clientId);

      List<String> clientFIO_separated=new <String>ArrayList();

      clientFIO_separated.add(clientFIO.get(0).getClFamily());
      clientFIO_separated.add(clientFIO.get(0).getClFirstName());
      clientFIO_separated.add(clientFIO.get(0).getClSecName());

      return clientFIO_separated;  

  } 

 public String ClAuthSubmit() 
            throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException  
    {

    ClientDAOImpl clientDAOImpl = new ClientDAOImpl();

    FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

      boolean valid= clientDAOImpl.rightClient(clientId, clPass);;
        if (valid) {
              HttpSession session = SessionBean.getSession();
              session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);
               return("success_ClientAuth");
        }       
            else{

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Вы ввели неверные данные","");
            context.addMessage(null, message);
            return(null);
        }

        }
public String logout() {
    FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
         session.setAttribute("userlogged","0");
         session.setAttribute("ID", clientId);

         return "loggedout";
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, BalusC. Problem is in Project bean, setters not invoking by clicking commandbutton.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `clientBean` and `beanClient`, which one is correct ? I believe that this causes your JSF page to get confused and to possibly initiate two different beans (or at least throw some unrendered exception)., in consequence causing page control/data issues.

Comment: Hi. beanClient just contains some methods to logout user with role "Client", and clientBean is model bean. Adn problems caused by projectBean - model for Project.

Comment: you might wanna try to set up debug breakpoint in the getter for text you'd expect to appear on screen to see whether this value is requested by the page at all.